# PDE, wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

First find the solution to the linear homogeneous wave equation
with wave speed $1$ and with initial conditions $u(x, 0) = \sin x$, $u_t(x, 0) = 0.$ Then calculate
$u_t(0, t).$

I'm stuck on this question by calculating $u_t(0, t).$
So first the general solution for $u_{tt} = u_{xx}$ is $$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2}[\phi(x + t) + \phi(x - t)] + \frac{1}{2} \int_{x - t}^{x + t} \psi(s)\,{\rm d}s$$ which is d’Alembert’s formula. 
With initial condition $u(x, 0) = \sin x$, $u_t(x, 0) = 0.$ It gives

$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2}[\phi(x) + \phi(x)] + \frac{1}{2} \int_{x}^{x}0\,{\rm d}s,$$so

$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(x + t) + \sin(x - t)].$$

This is where I got stuck, because I'm not sure what to do with $u_t(0,t)$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If $u_t(x,0) = 0$, what is the issue? We don't care about $u_t(0,t)$ when applying d'Alembert's formula anyway. You can even simplify what you want further to end up with $$u(x,t) = \sin x \cos t.$$And indeed, $u(x,0) = \sin x$ because $\cos 0 = 1$, and $u_t(x,0) = 0$ because $\sin 0 = 0$. Moreover $$u_{tt}(x,t) - u_{xx}(x,t) = -\sin x\cos t - (-\sin x \cos t) = 0.$$So $u_t(0,t) = -\sin 0 \sin t = 0$. You were essentially done without realizing.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm still a bit confused. Like how did you get $u(x,t)$ = sin$x$cos$t$. Are you simply looking at initial condition and concluded that? And for some reasons I thought the question asks me to calculate the initial condition of $u_t(0,t)$, but the way you did makes sense to me.

Comment: Oops, it's trigonometry identities. I haven't use it approximately 2 years. Sorry for my silly question.

Comment: I expanded $\sin(x+t)$ and $\sin(x-t)$ and cancelled terms. Next: your goal is to find $u_t(0,t)$, right? But d'Alembert's formula gave you something much better -- the concrete formula for $u(x,t)$. Just differentiate with respect to $t$ and plug $x=0$.

Comment: Yes, but differentiating with respect to $t$ isn't should be $u_t(0,t)$ = -sin$x$ sin $t$ = -sin($0$)sin $t$ = $0$? What am I missing here.

Comment: Oh yes. That was a mistake on my part, thanks for pointing. Fixed.